# manual query vs trigger function output

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm having one hell of a weird "bug", I am running postgres db, since having a view for some data would be "slow" I have set a trigger function that is inserting query data into table, deletes old data and so on.

Issue that I'm having is that weirdly data doesn't transfer correctly(one whole column is null and it's always the same column) when it's set in that so called flow(function + trigger), but when I run that same query step by step it loads the table as it should.

This is how that function goes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.header_details()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO public.header_details

(match_id, "homeTeam", "awayTeam", "leagueName", bet, "desc", "a", b, "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "Flag")

SELECT a.*,
mz."odd" as "a",
bb."odd" as b,
ab."odd" as "c",
obb."odd" as "d",
bo."odd" as "e",
sb."odd" as "f",
mxb."odd" as "g",
pinb."odd" as "h",
pwin."odd" as "j",
'new' as "Flag"

    
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT "match_id","homeTeam","awayTeam","leagueName",a."bet",b."desc" FROM public.latest_odds a
    JOIN public.bet_dim b ON a."bet" = b."bet"
) a
LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'a'
) mz
ON a."homeTeam" = mz."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = mz."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=mz."bet"
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'b'
) bb
ON a."homeTeam" = bb."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = bb."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=bb."bet"
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'c'
) ab
ON a."homeTeam" = ab."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = ab."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=ab."bet"
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'e'
    ) bo
ON a."homeTeam" = bo."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = bo."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=bo."bet"
    
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'f'
    ) sb
ON a."homeTeam" = sb."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = sb."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=sb."bet"
    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'Oktagon'
    ) obb
ON a."homeTeam" = obb."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = obb."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=obb."bet"     
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'g'
    )mxb
ON a."homeTeam" = mxb."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = mxb."awayTeam"  AND a."bet"=mxb."bet"
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'h'
    ) pinb
ON a."homeTeam" = pinb."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = pinb."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=pinb."bet"  
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT "homeTeam","awayTeam","odd","bet"
    FROM   public.latest_odds
    WHERE "bookie" = 'j'
    ) pwin
ON a."homeTeam" = pwin."homeTeam" AND a."awayTeam" = pwin."awayTeam" AND a."bet"=pwin."bet";     

UPDATE public.header_details
SET "Flag" = 'old'
WHERE "Flag" = 'current';

UPDATE public.header_details
SET "Flag" = 'current'
WHERE "Flag" = 'new';

DELETE FROM public.header_details
WHERE "Flag" = 'old';

 RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.header_details()
    OWNER TO doadmin;
```

This function is being triggered after insertion on "base" table.

Column that is always null is **bo."odd" as "E"**

Do you guys have any idea why it differs? I have tried troubleshooting everything, no idea why would that specific column always be null when the table gets loaded from trigger function...

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

edit:

now I'm just getting inconsistent data, now different column for some rows are being null through the function while manually data is populated... :o

[manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AztG3.png)

vs

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FugLs.png)

trigger creation script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER header_details
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.odds_data
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.header_details();
```

table creation script:

```
-- Table: public.header_details

-- DROP TABLE public.header_details;

CREATE TABLE public.header_details
(
    match_id bigint,
    "homeTeam" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "awayTeam" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "leagueName" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    bet text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "desc" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "a" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    b text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "c" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "d" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "e" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "f" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "g" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "h" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "j" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Flag" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.header_details
    OWNER to doadmin;
```

[data sample and how it should look like(no idea how to paste plain text:o)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pACft.png)

[how it looks in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A8s9.png)
vs
[how it looks through query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPbon.png)
when looking through whole dataset difference is 1500 non null rows for the query vs ~450 trigger function

Comment: You will need to provide the `TRIGGER` definition as well as the complete function body as update to your question. Also what column is being set to `NULL`?

Comment: i tried explaining a bit better and also added function code with dummy column names

Comment: Well if your column aliases("A", "B", "C", etc) are supposed to match the `WHERE "bookie"=` then they don't for `bo."odd"` and `sb."odd"` as examples. Are you sure you are selecting the correct data. The `LEFT JOINS` will return `NULL` for items that can't be found.

Comment: i've type id incorrectly in the post above, now i've edited, sorry :(
i don't think that it has anything with correctness of query as i am getting different results when i am manually running it vs when it's nested in trigger function.
I've added screenshots of different outputs. :o

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects (triggers, trigger functions, etc.) involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: hopefully i've added everything that would be needed, the only thing that i didn't is that data sample in text form, not sure how to go about that part... thanks!

Comment: In summary you are far better off addressing your performance issue (you might just need an index) than using triggers to move data around. Triggers are definitely a last resort and to be avoided.

Comment: are you confident that the inconsistency is not coming up from the update/delete within the same DB session without commit/rollback/savepoint. Surely it would not be felt if the SQL is executed separately

Comment: i'm using triggers to "refresh" this referencing table with the newest data and avoid using views for the sake of performance(that query would be frontend killer unfortunately) :/

Comment: @ErfanBashar that's a good hint, i'll try separating those things even tho what still doesn't gets in my head is why would some random rows be null and other don't O.o

Comment: i've separated the deletion flow from insertion + altered columns that are decimal to be decimal and not textual, maybe that will help as I have no other idea

Comment: nope, still same...
added SS's for the reference

Comment: I just have to reiterate: you should be absolutely certain that you can't address your performance issue through proper indexing etc., because introducing triggers is a whole new world of pain to deal with